# Obtaining Cartesian X & Y values from Lat/Long

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

From an aeronautical obstacle survey, I have a list of 500+ obstacles with Lat, Long and Ortho Elevation information. Using ArcMap 10.3; how do I obtain Cartesian X & Y values of all the obstacles with a particular runway end point (i.e. Runway Threshold) as origin. X/Y values of the obstacles are to be computed along/perpendicular to runway axis.

Comment: You need to project the lat/long dataset into a local coordinate system, for example if you were working in the UK it would be British National Grid. So you need to find out where your data is and choose a sensible coordinate system.

Comment: Suggest you look here: http://epsg.io/

Comment: You could create a custom azimuthal equidistant projection with the center at the runway endpoint. Project all obstacles and the runway endpoint into it. Now you can calculate the distances between them.